# Error in Async method that stops after Handler Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a method that updates the icons on the Main activity, I want to run that method every 3 seconds, but when I make that, my app stops.
I put the Handler because the try-catch did not work as I guest.

```
// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default)
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Define the code block to be executed
Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        obtenerModulosActivos();
        Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");
    }
};

// Run the above code block on the main thread after 2 seconds
handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 3000);
```

That is how I use the Handler.
(the obtenerModulos() is an async method).
Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: You have to to post obtenerModulosActivos.

Comment: You question isn't clear to me. But if I remember correctly, your runnableCode will only run once in the above code. You would need to add handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); as the last line of the run method to get it to be called every 3 seconds.